# JSF Pages goes away

Tags: jsf, netbeans, facelets, primefaces

I'm working with JSF and PrimeFaces and I am using Facelets as view technology. But I got an issue for which I can't find out the cause of the problem and the solution.

This is the Facelets template:

```
<div id="right">
    <div id="top">
        <ui:insert name="top"></ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-top">
            <ui:insert name="content-top"></ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="content-content">
            <ui:insert name="content-content"></ui:insert>
        </div>                    
    </div>                
</div>
```

I'm using `<p:layout>` and `<p:tabView>` in `content-content`. When I try to add for example `<h:form>` to `content-top`, then I lose `content-content` from my index. How is this caused and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by removing form id
Hope that help's someone